# Theme support title tag - how to replace the default WP separator (with a filter)?

Tags: theme-development, title, wp-title, add-theme-support

I'm developing a theme for Themeforest and one of their requirements is about the  tag. Themeforest [states their requirement](https://help.author.envato.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000479946) as follows:

*The theme must let WordPress add and manage the title. This is done by adding `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );` to functions.php instead of using `wp_title()` in the document head.*

The current output is on the home page: '`Site title - Site tagline`'. On other pages it is '`Post or page title - Site tagline`'.

The separator is '-'. Can anyone give an example of a filter for this, so that I can change the separator to '|' or a character of my choice?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The title tag shouldn't be determined by the theme. Remove the `<title>` tag entirely. WordPress will output it at `<?php wp_head(); ?>`.

Comment: Ok @JacobPeattie thanks. I removed it and currently it displays only the website name. How should I modify that?

Comment: On every page? Make sure to remove the entire `<title>` tag, not just the `wp_title()` part. So `bloginfo()` should be removed to, as well as the HTML.

Comment: Yes, I removed everything. There is now nothing in my header.php file. The only thing I have is the theme support for title tag in functions.php. Yeah, I want to modify it on every page, so [PAGE NAME OR POST NAME OR CATEGORY NAME OR WHATEVER] [SEPERATOR ( "|" )] [BLOGINFO NAME].

Comment: It looks like title-tag uses [wp_get_document_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_document_title/) which, at first glance, does append the site title if you're not on the home page? There are filters there to override the separator and more too.

Comment: @ralphsmit How the title tag is structured shouldn't depend on the theme. That's the point of this rule. I'm only trying to figure out if the default behaviour is working correctly. When you view a post, what is currently displayed? The website URL, website name, or post title?

Comment: You're correct, the structure is as follows: Home page: SITE TITLE - TAGLINE. Other pages: POST TITLE - SITE TITLE. So the separator is '-'. I think I missed the point of theme support for title-tag completely ;-), so I updated the question. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Ok, so the title tag is working correctly then. I still maintain that the theme has no business modifying the title separator. It’s not it’s job. Changing themes shouldn’t result in this important tag changing.

Comment: Ok @JacobPeattie that's a good point. I'll think about it and probably leave it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [document_title_separator](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_separator/) filter.

So in your case:

```
<?php
function theme_prefix_filter_document_title_separator() {
    return '|';
}
add_filter( 'document_title_separator', 'theme_prefix_filter_document_title_separator' );
?>
```

Comment: Hey Fränk, thanks for the answer! Is it correct that a filter always requires some input and then replaces something with that input?

Comment: More or less: in this case, [the calling code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.2/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1120) passes in its default value for separator, `-`, as an argument to the filter. But in this case you're just discarding that value and returning a new one. (I'd still probably accept the argument and pass argument count 1 to add_filter, but I guess it doesn't matter.)